# MD5 hash of a string which is already md5 hashed: Syntax error

Tags: c, md5sum

I wanted to generate md5 hash of a string which is already md5 hashed. This is what I have done! I have looped it but unfortunately, it is showing some error "sh: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected". 
I hope it has something to do with "strcat" inside the loop. 
Somehow inside the loop the lines

```
strcpy(command,"echo ");
strcat(command,str);
```

are ignored. I am lost here!

Can anybody help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char str[100], command[100];
   char var[100];
   int i;
   printf("Enter the string:\n");
   scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
   printf("\nString is: %s\n\n",str);
   for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
       strcpy(command,"echo ");
       strcat(command,str);
       strcat(command," | md5sum");
       strcat(command," | cut -c1-32");
       fp = popen(command, "r");
       fgets(var, sizeof(var), fp);
       pclose(fp);
       strcpy(str,var);
   }
   printf("The md5 has is :\n");
   printf("%s\n", var);   
   return 0;     

}
```

Comment: Io redirection is something the shell does; not something you do through a `popen`. If you really want to redirect from one process to another it's possible, but considerably more involved than just copy/pasting what you would type at a shell prompt (which looks to be what you're trying). Dare I ask, why aren't you using a crypto lib like OpenSSL ? making MD5 hashes of *anything* is near trivial with that toolkit.

Comment: thanks for this input WhozCraig. I will try this alternate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `fgets` which keep linefeed on read buffer.

From man fgets:

> **fgets()** reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer**. A terminating null byte (`\0`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

So you may want to replace the `\n` by some `\0`. You can do it with `strcspn`:

```
   ...           
   fgets(var, sizeof(var), fp);
   pclose(fp);
   strcpy(str,var);

   /* remove first \n in str*/
   str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';

   ...
```

Comment: Also it should escape a lot of special characters, like the redirection chars (`|`, `>`, `<`) and all the quotes. Anyway it is strange to do this via shell, using a library is definitely the way to go. Only as an experiment this is acceptable, still the escaping should be done.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu and Ho Zong, I have managed to fix my current code. But will use a library and rewrite it. Thanks a lot